# .htaccess not properly redirecting complete range of associated urls

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to set up my .htaccess file to redirect all traffic to https://www.example.com using the following:

```html
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

But it doesn't work correctly in all instances.

It correctly redirects the following:

```
http://www.example.com
http://www.example.com.au
http://www.example.net

http://example.com
http://example.com.au
http://example.net

https://www.example.net
```

It does not redirect the following:

```
https://www.example.com.au

https://example.com
https://example.com.au
https://example.net
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To redirect to `https://www`  you can use the following

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This will redirect all http or https urls to `https://www.example.com` .

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this 301 Redirect.

Comment: Thanks for this. It looks like it should work, but from the 'problem' urls, it only fixed https://example.com, with https://www.example.com.au, https://example.com.au and https://example.net still not redirecting.

Comment: ^ you'll have to hover over the urls to see them, they turned into links :(

Comment: @Dr_Hoon The rule should redirect all the domains pointing to your document root. Are you sure your `example.net` site is correctly pointing to the root of  main domain? And what happens when you type this in your browser?

Comment: I'm hosting multiple domains on my server, so all 'example' urls point to a single subfolder 'example', and they all work. The .htaccess file is in the root of the subfolder. The urls that don't redirect, such as https://example.net successfully point to the page, but the url remains unchanged in the address bar ie doesn't redirect to https://www.example.com.